# cleveref does not show the correct equation tag with subnumcases

Tags: cleveref, cases

[image]

The tag typsets as intends but its cross referencing does not.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{subnumcases}{f(x)=}
    1 & $x\geq0$
    \label{positive-subnum}
    \\
    0 & $x<0$
    \label{negative-subnum}
\end{subnumcases}
    
See the second case \cref{negative-subnum} or the first \cref{positive-subnum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What output is expected exactly?

Comment: You realize that you write `See the second case \cref{negative-subnum} or the first \cref{negative-subnum}` and **not** `See the second case \cref{negative-subnum} or the first \cref{positive-subnum}`?

Comment: @cfr
I edited the question. I expect `eq. (1b)` and `eq. (1a)`

Comment: It makes sense now you've edited the code - thanks. I'm wondering if this is to do with `eqnarray`. `cases` manual says parts are based on `eqnarray`, which `cleveref` doesn't support (manual p25). If so, I suspect you'd need to implement the environment differently or avoid `cleveref` in these instances. But this is just a guess - I haven't looked at the code. (I'll try to later if I get a chance.)

Comment: I looked and I suspect something along these lines is going on, but it would take (me) a lot of disentangling of code. Hopefully somebody who knows these packages better will cast some light on the situation. As far as I can tell `cases.sty` seems to reset `\refstepcounter` in `subnumcases` so the usual cross-referencing stuff is suspended and I *think* `cleveref.sty` relies on that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but the regular label is correct, while `cleveref`'s auxiliary one is not.  This is what we find in the aux file for the MWE:

```tex
\newlabel{positive-subnum}{{1a}{1}{}{}{}}
\newlabel{positive-subnum@cref}{{[subequation][1][1]1a}{[1][1][]1}}
\newlabel{negative-subnum}{{1b}{1}{}{}{}}
\newlabel{negative-subnum@cref}{{[subequation][1][1]1a}{[1][1][]1}}
```

So `negative-subnum` has the correct default reference `1b`, but in `negative-subnum@cref` we find `[subequation][1][1]1a`. Thus, it seems some sort of bad interaction between `cases` and `cleveref`, of lack of support for their use together.

If you're willing, `zref-clever` does get this one right:

```tex
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{abbrev}

\begin{document}

\begin{subnumcases}{f(x)=}
    1 & $x\geq0$
    \label{positive-subnum}
    \\
    0 & $x<0$
    \label{negative-subnum}
\end{subnumcases}

See the second case \zcref{negative-subnum} or the first \zcref{positive-subnum}

\end{document}
```

[image]